# Extracting Data from NSMuableDictionary to NSString and compering to String issue

Tags: iphone, ios, variable-assignment, nsmutabledictionary

Im Extracting Data from NSMuableDictionary to NSString and try compering to String like this:

```
   NSDictionary *error = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
   NSString *errorCode = [[NSString alloc]init];
   error = [sing.globalCallsDitionary valueForKey:@"Error"];
   NSLog(@"error code %@",[error valueForKey:@"error_code"]);
   errorCode = [error valueForKey:@"error_code"];
   if ([errorCode isEqualToString:@"-1"]) {
```

When the if statement executed i get this error talking about an array, the error looks like this:

```
2012-04-27 06:34:49.686 CallBiz[10319:707] error code (
    "-1"
)
2012-04-27 06:35:00.602 CallBiz[10319:707] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16fc10
2012-04-27 06:35:00.608 CallBiz[10319:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16fc10'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3541f88f 0x36846259 0x35422a9b 0x35421915 0x3537c650 0xb2a3 0x353793fd 0x32458faf 0x32458f6b 0x32458f49 0x32458cb9 0x324595f1 0x32457ad3 0x324574c1 0x3243d83d 0x3243d0e3 0x3667222b 0x353f3523 0x353f34c5 0x353f2313 0x353754a5 0x3537536d 0x36671439 0x3246be7d 0x2e61 0x28fc)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

It is as xCode is looking on my `NSString *errorCode = [[NSString alloc]init];` as if it is an `NSArray`, can someone help me with this?

Comment: I don't think so if statement have any problem...

Comment: check before and after code by if statement..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error occurs because your errorCode came as a array, instead of string. If you are sure that only 1 object come here, then you can use -

```
if ([[errorCode objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"-1"])
```

It will work, although it will through a warning, because errorCode is defined as a string object. So you ned to sure what data you are getting in response and then define data structure appropriately.

Comment: Thanks RIP, it worked, and i changed the definition of the errorCode to an NSArray as well

Comment: Perfect!!Also you need to make sure that error code always came as first object of array.

Comment: You might want to be careful, as it's an an array that suggests there may be more than one error code provided. You might want to use something like [errorCode containsObject:@"-1'] instead?